# How to execute java jshell command as inline from shell or windows commandLine

Tags: java, java-9, jshell

Are there any way to execute java command on REPL (`jshell`) as inline command without launching it?

**E.g. Perl inline command**

```
$perl -e 'printf("%06d", 19)'
000019
```

**I have to launch jshell to run any command:**

```
$jshell
|  Welcome to JShell -- Version 9
|  For an introduction type: /help intro
jshell> String.format("%06d", 19)
$1 ==> "000019"
```

I found similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46426526/how-to-run-a-jshell-file), but it's not feasible solution to create a separate `jsh` file for individual command.

Another solution on same post is: `echo "1+2"|jshell`

```
temp=`echo 'String.format("%06d", 19)'|jshell`
echo $temp
```

**Ouch output**

```
| Welcome to JShell -- Version 9 | For an introduction type: /help intro jshell> String.format("%06d", 19) $1 ==> "000019" jshell>
```

I am expecting `$temp` only print `000019`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run a JShell File?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46426526/how-to-run-a-jshell-file)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I checked the suggested post, it's not feasible to create a separate file for individual command. One can have `n` number of commands to execute at different places.

Comment: [One of the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46426620/1746118) on the same post suggests using `echo` and doesn't require the script though. Did you try that? *commands to execute at different places.* what does different places mean here?

Comment: I tried it but the response is not expected. please check post.

Comment: I am trying $temp to assign only `3` and exclude rest of info. Is there any option to skip jshell to print version info?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156711/discussion-between-squid-and-nullpointer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the `normal` feedback mode is used in your interaction with `JShell` and this mode prints command output, Declaration, Commands and Prompt. Read [Introduction to jshell feedback modes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/jshell/feedback-modes.htm#JSHEL-GUID-906D1D0B-76AD-4AFD-9229-96C6FD823B4A) for more details.

Steps to get command output:

1. Run `jshell` in `concise` feedback mode to skip Command and Declaration details, it will still print prompt and value.

   ```
    $ echo 'String.format("%06d", 19)' | jshell --feedback concise
      jshell> String.format("%06d", 19)
      $1 ==> "000019"
   ```
2. Filter 2nd row from result using `sed`-

   ```
   echo 'String.format("%06d", 19)' | jshell --feedback concise | sed -n '2p'
   ```
3. Extract only value and exclude other details-

   ```
   echo 'String.format("%06d", 19)' | jshell --feedback concise | sed -n '2p' |sed -En 's/[^>]*>(.+)/\1/gp'
   ```

Comment: Sure is this working in a Windows CMD / PowerShell command line? I've been testing with Windows 10, JDK11 and not working: JShell opens but freezes on the `jshell>` command.
Neither works with WSL.

Answer (score -1):

If you use System.out.println, you will not need the second sed

```
echo "System.out.println(\"$JAVA_HOME\");" | jshell --feedback concise | sed -n '2p'
```