# How do you load an external file in JShell?

Tags: java, jshell

JShell is the interactive REPL command line for Java.

If I have a Java class with some methods that I would like to play around with interactively in a .java file, how do I load that file in?

Let's say I have the file `HelloWorld.java`:

```
class HelloWorld
{
    public static void main(String[] argsv)
    {
    }

    public static void doStuff()
    {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
}
```

and I'd like to load up JShell and be able to call the `doStuff()` method from the command line. How do I do that?

Starting `JShell` with the file name as `$ JShell HelloWorld.java` didn't work. Nor classfile. I still get the error `cannot find symbol |    symbol:   variable HelloWorld` from JShell. Using the `/open <filename>` command gave same result.

Comment: You could: 1) Read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/jshell.htm#JSWOR-GUID-C337353B-074A-431C-993F-60C226163F00). --- 2) Do what it says on startup, i.e. `For an introduction type: /help intro`. --- Then you'll find the `/open` command, which is the same as specifying the file on the `jshell` command-line. --- Running `jshell HelloWorld.java` or command `/open HelloWorld.java` inside the shell, will declare the class, then entering `HelloWorld.doStuff();` will execute the method and print "Hello world". --- Voting to close as **not reproducible**, since it works fine.

Comment: @Andreas As I wrote in my OP, I tried doing `jshell HelloWorld.java` and it didn't work. When I typed `HelloWorld` or `HelloWorld.doStuff()` on the JShell prompt, I got `cannot find symbol
|    symbol:   variable HelloWorld`. Using the `/open` command gave same result. The command gave no error, but I still could not call the imported methods. Am I missing some secret step?

Comment: @Andreas The documentation, which I had read before posting here, was not especially helpful. It mentions loading a file of snippets, but no mention of loading a Java class. And no sample usage. Unfortunately your suggestion did not work for me. Is it really "not reproducible"? Did it really work for you?

Comment: This post suggests it's not even possible. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46429154/336563

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Unable to reproduce:** The problem described in the question ("didn't work") is not reproducible, since it's working without issue.

Here is a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with the working steps, testing on Java 9 and Java 14.

First, to verify the content of the Java source file:

```shell
C:\Temp>type HelloWorld.java
```

```java
class HelloWorld
{
    public static void main(String[] argsv)
    {
    }

    public static void doStuff()
    {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
}
```

We can run that with JShell from Java 9, loading file using command-line:

```shell
C:\Temp>jshell HelloWorld.java
```

```java
|  Welcome to JShell -- Version 9.0.4
|  For an introduction type: /help intro

jshell> HelloWorld.doStuff()
Hello world
```

As can be seen, the Java source file is loaded just fine, and the `static` method is called without issue.

We can also run that with JShell from Java 14, loading file using `/open` command:

```shell
C:\Temp>jshell
```

```java
|  Welcome to JShell -- Version 14
|  For an introduction type: /help intro

jshell> HelloWorld.doStuff()
|  Error:
|  cannot find symbol
|    symbol:   variable HelloWorld
|  HelloWorld.doStuff()
|  ^--------^

jshell> /open HelloWorld.java

jshell> HelloWorld.doStuff()
Hello world
```

We first tried to run before the `/open` command, to prove that `HelloWorld` did not exist, i.e. proving that it is the `/open` command that declares the class.

Comment: I thought I tried it exactly as you suggested earlier and still got the error. But I'm doing it again and it is working. Apparently the earlier tests had a typo. I am suitably embarassed and apologize for wasting your time. Let the flogging commence. And thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue to this but in my case for whatever reason the class wouldn't load via the `/open` command unless I removed `public` from the class declaration.  I don't know if this was do to a bug in my version of `jshell` (11.0.2 running on MacOSX Catalina), or it's something specific about jshell itself.